# Custom command to minimize current window

Tags: user-interface, elementary-project, hot-corners

I need to set a hot corner to minimize current window. But the only default option is to maximise current window or set a custom command. I can't figure out the command line command to minimise a window.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Desktop > Hot Corners, select the corner you want and choose `Execute custom command`:

[image: custom command]

Then add the following code:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.behavior hotcorner-bottomright 'minimize-current'
```